# How do I run code after Angular animations?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-router, angular-animations

I have set up a slide animation in Angular 7 when changing the route. The problem I have right now is that the animation is stuttering, because the Component that I'm navigating to is executing code during the animation in the `OnInit` lifecycle.

How do I initialize code for the component after the animation has finished to prevent frame drops?

Edit:

I'm using router animations, here's my setup:

`app.component.html`:

```
<div [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

`app.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  animations: [routeAnimations]
})
export class AppComponent {
  prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData.animation;
  }
}
```

`app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'sign-in',
    loadChildren: './modules/sign-in/sign-in.module#SignInModule',
    data: {animation: 'slideLeft'}
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    data: {animation: 'slideRight'}
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`animations.ts`:

```
export const routeAnimations =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('slideLeft => slideRight', [
      // ...a bunch of animation code...
    ]),
    transition('slideRight => slideLeft', [
      // ...a bunch of animation code...
    ])
  ]);
```

Comment: You may find this article much helpful: [https://alligator.io/angular/animation-callbacks/](https://alligator.io/angular/animation-callbacks/)

Comment: @HarunYılmaz I already saw this, this isn't really helpful as the animation start and end events are fired for a single component using angular animations. I'm using router animations and need OnInit code for each component I'm navigating to. The OnInit code needs to run after the router animation though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to expose the *start* and *done* events from the animation to child components.

```
@Component({..})
export class AppComponent {
    public start$: Subject<AnimationEvent> = new Subject();
    public done$: Subject<AnimationEvent> = new Subject();
}

<div [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)"
     (@routeAnimations.start)="start$.next($event)"
     (@routeAnimations.done)="done$.next($event)">
   <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Now inject the `AppComponent` into child components used in the router.

```
@Component({..})
export class ChildComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private readonly _destroyed: Subject<void> = new Subject();
    public constructor(app: AppComponent) {
        app.done$
           .pipe(first(), takeUntil(this._destroyed))
           .subscribe(()=> {
               // do special work here
           });
    }
    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this._destroyed.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job!

Comment: Thank you for showing where to find and bind the appropriate events! :) Not to fond of this particular implementation with subjects and injecting AppComponent into ChildComponent though...

Comment: Why not put these subjects in a service, and injecting that service where it's needed?